# JavaScript Loop not ending when it should

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am making a game of 21 (also known as blackjacks), and I am not sure why my program is ignoring this conditional statement, where if the user gets their card value above 21, the loop ends, can someone tell me what the problem here would be? Thank you. (This code isn't finished, so excuse the messiness.) (also see comment that says "problem below")

```
let cardRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var cardOne = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardRange.length)];
var cardTwo = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardRange.length)];
var cardTotal = cardOne + cardTwo;
var comScore = 18;
var i;
var extracard;


alert(`Your card numbers are ${cardOne} and ${cardTwo}!`);
//user gets to draw 5 cards in total
for(i = 0; i<3;){
var input = prompt(`Which makes your card total ${cardTotal}. Would you like to draw another card? (Type in 1 for yes, 0 for no, or select cancel to return to home.)`);


if (input === null){
    i+=3;
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
else if (input === "1"){
    i++;
    extraCard = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardRange.length)];
    alert(`This card's number is ${extraCard}!`);
    cardTotal = extraCard + cardTotal;

}
else if (input === "0"){
    i+=3;
}
//problem below
else if (cardTotal >=22){
    i+=3;
}
//not working, loop will not end.
else{
alert("Lmao wrong input you rart");
}
}


function pontoonOutput(){
    if (cardTotal > comScore && cardTotal < 22){
        document.write(`You got ${cardTotal}, and the AI player got ${comScore}. Which means.... You win!`);
    }
    else if (cardTotal === comScore){
        document.write(`You got ${cardTotal}, and the AI player got ${comScore}. Which means.... It is a tie!`);
    }
    //this outputs if the user gets above 22
    else if (cardTotal >= 22){
        alert("BUST!");
        document.write(`Your card number is ${cardTotal}, which is above 21. Which means.... You lose!`);
    }
    //what should happen if line 29 is picked up. ^
    else{
        document.write(`You got ${cardTotal}, and the AI player got ${comScore}. Which means.... You lose!`);
    }
    }
    
    pontoonOutput();
```

Comment: That should actually work.

Comment: It doesn't, it still shows the prompt for the variable "input" when the user has a cardTotal of 22 or above.

Comment: As a remark, this is a very bad pattern. 1) You should ideally only use "for" loops when you know upon entering the loop how many times you should run it. Else use a "while" loop 2) If you really need to exit "for" loop early, user break();

Comment: I totally missed the guard point! Check answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it is part of an `else`, so as long as they input `1` or `0` or `null`, it won't ever hit.  Your probably just want to move it into it's own condition at the end:

```js
let cardRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var cardOne = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
var cardTwo = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
var cardTotal = cardOne + cardTwo;
var comScore = 18;
var i;
var extracard;


alert(`Your card numbers are ${cardOne} and ${cardTwo}!`);
//user gets to draw 5 cards in total
for (i = 0; i < 3;) {
    var input = prompt(`Which makes your card total ${cardTotal}. Would you like to draw another card? (Type in 1 for yes, 0 for no, or select cancel to return to home.)`);


    if (input === null) {
        i += 3;
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    } else if (input === "1") {
        i++;
        extraCard = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
        alert(`This card's number is ${extraCard}!`);
        cardTotal = extraCard + cardTotal;

    } else if (input === "0") {
        i += 3;
    } else {
        alert("Lmao wrong input you rart");
    }
    //problem below
    if (cardTotal >= 22) {
        i += 3;
    }
    //not working, loop will not end.

}


function pontoonOutput() {
    if (cardTotal > comScore && cardTotal < 22) {
        document.write(`You got ${cardTotal}, and the AI player got ${comScore}. Which means.... You win!`);
    } else if (cardTotal === comScore) {
        document.write(`You got ${cardTotal}, and the AI player got ${comScore}. Which means.... It is a tie!`);
    }
    //this outputs if the user gets above 22
    else if (cardTotal >= 22) {
        alert("BUST!");
        document.write(`Your card number is ${cardTotal}, which is above 21. Which means.... You lose!`);
    }
    //what should happen if line 29 is picked up. ^
    else {
        document.write(`You got ${cardTotal}, and the AI player got ${comScore}. Which means.... You lose!`);
    }
}

pontoonOutput();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are checking the card total in the same if...else statement, but AFTER checking for the "0" or "1" input. So if the user enters "0" or "1", your code will process those conditions, and it will never get to the card total check.

There are many ways to fix this problem. One solution is to move the card total check into a separate if condition, after the main if...else logic. Something like this:

```js
for(i = 0; i<3;){
  var input = prompt(`Which makes your card total ${cardTotal}. Would you like to draw another card? (Type in 1 for yes, 0 for no, or select cancel to return to home.)`);

  if (input === null){
    // ...
  }
  else if (input === "1"){
    // ...
  }
  else if (input === "0"){
    // ...
  }

  // Keep separate from the main if...else logic to ensure it always gets run.
  if (cardTotal >=22){
    i+=3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `break` statement.
Try this instead:

```js
for(i = 0; i<3;){
  var input = prompt(`Which makes your card total ${cardTotal}. Would you like to draw another card? (Type in 1 for yes, 0 for no, or select cancel to return to home.)`);

  if (input === null){
    // ...
  }
  else if (input === "1"){
    // ...
  }
  else if (input === "0"){
    // ...
  }
  
  if (cardTotal >=22){
    //i += 3;
    break;
  }
}
```

now i see, it needed to be splited

Comment: This is likely to perform the same as the original.   See the srk and dave's answers to understand more

Comment: Better.  And I agree with you that `break` is preferable to increasing the value of `i ` when you want to exit the loop immediately.